# Getting Revel controller to return a cookie

Tags: session, cookies, go, revel

I've been able to store a custom cookie but I'm trying to save it for a session the store it in the database when a form is submitted. I use:

```
func (c Application) Index(id string) revel.Result {
cookie := http.Cookie{Name: "id", Value: id, Domain: "localhost", Path: "/"}
c.SetCookie(&cookie)
return c.Render()
}
```

but I cannot access it again. How could I retrieve it in a different function?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I was going about it all wrong. Revel sets cookies with the session.

```
Set: 
    c.Session[key] = value

Get:
    c.Session[key]
```